# Time Complexity of Binary Search?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

If I divide array size by 3 what will the running time of **Binary search**.

Comment: What do you think it is?

Comment: I asked you a question. You don’t answer a question with a question.

Comment: Don't know @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ What is the answer? Please tell me

Comment: Why most of the users are Downvoting the question?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Well if you want to be technical, Chintu asked a question first, and you replied with a question. So, you may want to apply your good advice "You don't answer a question with a question." to yourself ;)

Comment: @bitmask: if I were answering the question, I’d have written a post, not a comment, but good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With binary search you typically search in a sorted random access data structure like an array, by discarding half of the array with each comparison.  Hence, in `k` steps you effectively cover `2^k` entries. This yields a complexity of at most `log2(n)` of `n` elements.

With landau symbols, the base of the logarithm disappears because it is a constant: `O(log2(n)) = O(log(n) / log(2)) = O(log(n))`.

Now, if you, for some reason, can not only discard half of the values, but two thirds, by always knowing in which third the needle will end up in, this means you cover `3^k` many entries in `k` steps.

Hence, you get `log3(n)`. But this again reduces to the same time complexity as `log(3)` is a constant: `O(log3(n)) = O(log(n)/log(3)) = O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be still `log n` assuming your array is sorted.